# Entity framework, проблема с созданием сущностей

Tags: entity-framework

Добрый день. 
Строю сущности по существующей БД. Есть 3 таблицы items,books,articles. Связи items books один ко одному и items articles один ко одному. Для удобства дальнейшего создания DAL Хочу сделать 2 сущности books и articles которые будут содержать поля Items. До этого уже делал одну сущность из двух таблиц, все работало нормально, но сейчас столкнулся с такой ошибкой "Error 3033: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 488:EntitySets 'Books' and 'Articles' are both mapped to table 'Items'. Their primary keys may collide". Подскажите как решить проблему!!!

Comment: У вас edmx или code first? Если edmx, гляньте в дизайнер и подправьте mapping таблиц. Если code first, что в ваших атрибутах и `OnModelCreating`?

Comment: EDMX. А что конкретно подправить? просмотрел, так и не понял... И если возможность авт. генерировать несколько сущностей привязаных к одной табл?